# Rebuild LOB_DATA allocation unit

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, blob, rebuild

Is anyone aware of any way to rebuild a LOB_DATA allocation unit. I have a single column with IMAGE data type that is taking 2500 GB of space right now. However, the actual data stored in there is only about a quarter of that in size.

The table needs to stay online during this time, so a standard index rebuild is not going to work.  The data in the table gets cycled through every 30 days so if I could do something to better fill pages for new data, that would already help. However, the drive is going to be full in 4 days.

Any Ideas , no matter how complex, are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server Enterprise, you can use the ONLINE option and it will get rebuilt without taking the table offline.  That is not available in SQL Server Standard.  Your other option is to REORGANIZE rather than REBUILD.

Comment: Also, there may be another trick you can use specifically for LOB data and keeping it online: [link](http://www.sqlmag.com/blog/sql-server-questions-answered-28/database-administration/moving-lob-data-keeping-table-online-142703) but I don't know if that will be useful in your case with such a large group.  Check it out anyway and see if it could help.  Good luck